# Google Maps API - position/center by keyword (city name)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my web application I am using the gmap javascript API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ ). I am using the code below inside a function to position/center the gmap once a user has pressed a button.

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.setCenter(position);
```

This code uses the latitude and longitude. Instead of the latitude and longitude I would like to position/center the gmap based on a given keyword. For example, how can I position/center the gmap if the input is 'Paris'?

Comment: you can use the [google maps geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to get the lat/long of the required city

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use geocoder service of Maps JavaScript API to resolve your input (e.g. Paris) to coordinate and center the map.

Have a look at the following code sample

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
    zoom: 8
  });

  geocoder.geocode({'address': "Paris"}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });


}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Does not work. Always getting REQUEST_DENIED status even though I have provided API_KEY when embedding JS script.

Comment: @ Radek Strugalski Double check you project. Did you enable Maps JavaScript API and Geocoding API? Did you enable billing for your API key?

Comment: Yes, I found out yesterday that in order to use Geocode API you need enable it and pay extra for it. (5USD for 1000 calls or so).