# Getting "REQUEST_DENIED" even though all APIs are enabled for Google Maps Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

Really weird problem, and I have tried to find an issue for this problem.

I am trying to get Geolocation working with Google Maps JavaScript API, like this demo:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45153330/80389

In my console, I have enabled any APIs I think could be related to this;

[image]

And I have a totally unrestricted key:

[image]

And I have obviously replaced `KEY` in the HTTP call, but I am still getting;

[image]

> Geocoding Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:9002
>
> Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

Billing is enabled (even have money on my account).

What possibly more could I have missed?

(Also, without geolocation and only javascript maps API, it all works. The problem is with geolocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer: It should be the `Geodecoding` API, not `Geolocation`.

Answer (score 0):

Your key do not have any API restriction but you might have applied an application restriction, that controls which websites, IP addresses, or applications can use your API key.